# How to prevent the JSESSIONID showing in the URL

Tags: java, servlets, google-cloud-datastore, jsessionid

I have created an login page in servlet using Google Datastore, it is working fine. but sometimes its showing the JSESSIONID in the URL.

How can I prevent the JSESSIONID sending through the URL?
why its passing through the URL instead of request message?

Answer (score 5):

Add the following entry in your `web.xml`.

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

This will instruct the container that the client supports cookies and hence there is no need to put the `JSessionId` in the URL.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using `response.encodeURL()`? If so, try to remove it or disable "URL Rewriting" and check the URL.

See also:

- disableURLRewriting

[Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)

**Additional information**:

`response.encodeURL(URL)` adds `;jsessionid=xxxx...` to URL. To disable this(="URL Rewriting"),

Tomcat 7.0 or later:

```
<session-config>
  <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Tomcat 6.0:

```
<Context disableURLRewriting="true" ...
```

Comment: No I am not using `response.encodeURL()`,

Comment: You should *always* use `response.encodeURL` (or `response.encodeRedirectURL` if appropriate). If you want to disable sessions, use the configuration instead of breaking your application by not following the rules.