# Requested and authenticated emails differ

Tags: logout, google-authentication

[Error when trying to authorize another google user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEc5Y.png)

This issue came up when a google user has already authorized their account. When that user tries to authorize another email, this error came up.

Deleting all server-side cookie does not fix this problem but logging out the user by directing them to https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout (WARNING) does. However, that link will log out all Google users that are currently logged in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a cookie issue. JSESSIONID. An answer can be found here [How to prevent the JSESSIONID showing in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44673490/how-to-prevent-the-jsessionid-showing-in-the-url)